# octopack nuget package version

Tags: nuget, nuspec, octopack

My nupkg file seem to version 1.0.0.0 no matter what I did. 
I want to specify the version of the package using the version element inside my nuspec file as follow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>SpacePlanning.SavePlanogram</id>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <authors>Blah</authors>
    </metadata>
..
</package>
```

My  msbuild  command is

```
MSBuild.exe "%WORKSPACE%\LoadPlanogram.sln" /t:Build /p:Configuration=Debug /p:OctopusPackageConfiguration=Debug /p:RunOctoPack=true /p:OctoPackEnforceAddingFiles=true /p:OctopusPackageVersion=1.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSBuild parameter you're looking for is Octo**Pack**PackageVersion, not OctopusPackageVersion.

I believe that what you're asking (specify a hardcoded version in the *.nuspec* file and use that) is not possible.

You can choose to specify the version through the MSBuild parameter mentioned above, or in the *AssemblyInfo.cs* file, using the **AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute** or **AssemblyVersionAttribute**.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.1")]
```

or, if you want to create a [pre-release package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/prerelease-packages):

```
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.2.3-myhotfix+somemetadata")]
```

You can read about the inner workings of OctoPack when it comes to versioning the package here: [Using OctoPack Versioning](https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/nuget-packages/using-octopack#UsingOctoPack-Versionnumbers)

Comment: Emiel- My mistake! It does work when I changed the attribute /p:OctoPackPackageVersion=x.x.x.

However, if I remove the above parameter from the MSBUILD and use the AssemblyVersion to produce the version. It didn't seem to take effect, no matter what I changed it to.